Why do I get "NoneType object is not iterable" when filtering a list of dictionaries with list comprehension and handling None?
I'm trying to filter a list of dictionaries in Python using list comprehension. I am handling None values, but I keep getting the error "NoneType object is not iterable". I expected my code to skip None values, but it still throws the error. How can I fix this?
Here is my code to reproduce the problem:
def process_data(data, key):
    return [
        {k: [v for v in val if v > 10] for k, val in item.items() if k == key}
        for item in data
        if item is not None
    ]

data = [
    {'values': [5, 15, 25]},
    None,
    {'values': [8, 12, 20]},
    {'values': None},
    {'values': [7, 14, 21]}
]

filtered_data = process_data(data, 'values')
print(filtered_data)


You're not handling the None in {'values': None}…

To expand on what deceze said: You have a nested for loop. The inner loop is the one raising b/c None isn't iterable.
If you try rewriting the comprehensions as full loops and fill in the values by hand, you'll see the problem immediately.

If you have control over how data is produced, you might consider using {'values': []} instead of {'values': None}. None is nice when you really need to distinguish between the lack of a container and an empty container, but I don't think that's a common need.

Like the comments are saying, you are not handling the None within the 4th dictionary. There is no exception set up to deal with getting a None value within a dictionary, just if there is a None value instead of a dictionary. This is a simple fix though. Add another condition at the end of line 3 to make sure val isn't None. Here is the new code written out.
def process_data(data, key):
    return [
        {k: [v for v in val if v > 10] for k, val in item.items() if k == key and val is not None}
        for item in data
        if item is not None
    ]
.
.
.

